# Labeling points on matplotlib scatter plot from output of TSNE using pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

the question topic is a little complex because I need a lot of help lol.  To explain, I have a csv of data with labels (names) and numerical data...

```
name,post_count,follower_count,following_count,anonymous_pic,is_private,...
adam,3,997,435,0,0,1,0,0,0,0 bob,2,723,600,0,0,1,0,0,0,0
jill,11,3193,962,0,0,1,0,0,0,0 sara,0,225,298,0,0,1,0,0,0,0
.
.
```

and so on. This data is loaded into a pandas dataframe from the csv.  Now, I wish to pass only the numerical parts of this data into a sklearn.manifold class called TSNE (t-distributed stochastic neighbor embedding) which will output a list the same size as the input data, where each element of the new list is is list of size k (where k is the number of components specified as an argument to the TSNE class).  In my case k = 2.

I'm graphing this data on a 2-D scatter plot from matplotlib, and I'd like to be able to inspect the labels on the data.  I know matplotlib has an annotate feature in which points can be labeled, but how do I go about separating these labels from the data for TSNE? and if i just separate the labels prior to transformation, how can I go about ensuring that i'm relabeling the right points?

I'd like to be able to inspect these names, because I need to see if the transformation is useful on my data.  This way I can analyze a few really bizarre places and see if something interesting is happening.  Here is my code if you find it useful (Although I'll admit its just scratchwork)

```
# Data structuring
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

# Plotting
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set() # for plot styling

# Load data
df = pd.read_csv('user_data.csv')
print(df.head())

# sklearn
from sklearn.mixture import GMM
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE


tsne = TSNE(n_components = 2, init = 'random', random_state = 0)
lab_proj = tsne.fit_transform(df)

x = [i[0] for i in lab_proj]
y = [i[1] for i in lab_proj]

print(len(lab_proj))

df['PCA1'] = x 
df['PCA2'] = y 
model = GMM(n_components = 1, covariance_type = 'full')
model.fit(df)
y_gmm = model.predict(df)

df['cluster'] = y_gmm 
sns.lmplot('PCA1', 'PCA2', data = df, col='cluster', fit_reg = False)
plt.show()
```

Thanks!